# Trying to correct values using mutate case_when and it's not changing any values?

Tags: r

I have 4 csv files representing 4 different nests. I'm trying to combine them all into one spreadsheet. I have a few errors that were made when inputting data and I am trying to change them in R. For example, "GBGB" is written instead of "GBBG" for nest 4. This is the code I used:

```
nest.4 <- nest.4 %>% 
  mutate(Species = case_when(
    Species %in% c("GBGB") ~ "GBBG"))
```

but it didn't change any of my values! I also want to combine them all at the end once I fix these errors. I want to use :

```
nests.df <- left_join(nest.1, nest.2, nest.3, nest.4)
```

but I am getting this error message:
Error: `by` must be a (named) character vector, list, or NULL for natural joins

I'm just learning how to use R so I don't know if this is the right way to change values and combine datasets or not! Thanks!

Comment: Here is a [link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) about case_when and how to use it. To merge all of them you can do it with `Reduce(function(...)merge(..., by = your_var), list(nest.1, nest.2, ...)))`. To get more help please share a reproducible example along with expected outcome

Answer (score 1):

for the left_join function, you can only join 2 data.frames at once. The "nest.3" was seen by the function as the "by" argument, which is not what you want.
left_join takes arguments as follows:

> left_join(df1, df2, by=...)

there are also other arguments (check them out with `?left_join`), but I guess those are the ones most important for you.
You could do:

> left_join( left_join(df1,df2) , left_join(df3,df4) )

The `mutate` & `case_when` functions seem to be used correctly. Maybe your strings are levels? That sometimes messes things up. Try: `nest.4$Species`, if it gives you an overview of all the levels it might cause the problem. When you import your files (with read.csv or read.table or whatever you use), set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or you can also set `nest.4$Species = as.character(nest.4$species)` to remove the factors/levels.

Maybe also try `ifelse()` as an alternative to case_when, to see if it works in principal.

Comment: The `case_when` should be `case_when(Species %in% c("GBGB") ~ "GBBG",
TRUE ~ Species)` to ensure that when the condition is not met, all the rest of the Species values are not converted to NA.